# How to check if javascript typed arrays are supported?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

Would like to test with javascript 
if browser support typed array http://caniuse.com/#feat=typedarrays

i tryed this but seems not the good way because some browser have just a partial support..:

```
if(window.ArrayBuffer){alert('typed array supported')}
```

Comment: That's all that the Modernizr add-on test checks; what's the partial support you're worried about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems some browsers (IE10) doesn't support `Uint8ClampedArray`, and if that is a feature you intend to use, you can just check for it

```
if ( 'Uint8ClampedArray' in window ) { ...
```

If the check returns false, typed arrays **and/or** clamped arrays are not supported.
If you don't need `Uint8ClampedArray`, you can stick with what you've got, personally I like to use `in`

```
if ( 'ArrayBuffer' in window ) { ...
```